# How to make a fixed size button with PGU

Tags: python, pygame, pgu

I'm using python,pygame and PGU to develop a game. I'd like to create a fixed size button, but it seems `resize()` doesn't have any effect. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
app = gui.App()
top = gui.Container()
button = gui.Button("Start")
button.resize(200, 100)
top.add(button, 0, 0)
app.init(top, screen)
```

The button will always appear at the minimum size required to display its text. Is there any way to enforce the button size with PGU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a fixed size button, you should initialize it, passing width and height.

Remember that, if the dimensions in pixel aren't "large enough", it forces the button to have the minimum size required to display its text, also considering padding (from style/theme, which you can also configure) etc.

Theese are three useful (of course alternative) examples:

```
button = gui.Button("Start", width = 200)

button = gui.Button("Start", height = 100)

button = gui.Button("Start", width = 200, height = 100)
```

Where the one you are looking for is the last.

The question is rather old, but still useful for others, I think.

Comment: Thanks Luca, I'm no more working on that, but looking at the Button and Widget code it should work!